# ffmpeg how to get start_time and start_pst to 0

Tags: ffmpeg, converters, ffprobe, h.265

ffprobe showed that one of our videos has a start time that is incorrect, 2.1 (it has to be 0).

Does anybody know hot go get `start_pst` and `start_time` to 0?
I have been searching for hours and i did not yet find a way to force that to become 0.

Comment: What container format?

Comment: mp4, 
the final output skipps some frames when i start playing the video.

Comment: Unlike something like TS, mp4 doesn't not have a concept of a start time. A start time of 0 is implied. But mp4 does have something called edit lists. I'm guessing there is an edit list (possible due to B frames causing negative DTS at the start of the file.)

Comment: if it's MPEG then a start time of "1.0" or even "600.0" is sometimes normal/expected...anyway there is a SETPTS filter but I don't know if needed...

Comment: I did not know that about mp4 not having a native start time. thanks for that info. Had no success with an edit list yet. Does somebody happen to know the exact command to have an mp4 to start at zero? (tried a lot of methods already)

Comment: In my case it shows all videos having a start time of things like 0.151178, which I was wondering what the meaning of is...